# Filtering Objects in RecyclerView with a switch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a RecyclerView that i passed an`ArrayList<MovieCategory> list` to, and i want to filter it with a switch.Class MovieCategory has 4 boolean variables isAction, isComedy, isHorror and isThriller. So a movie can be: `isAction = true` if it's just an Action film, or it can be `isAction = true isComedy = true` if it's an action-comedy etc. There are 4 switches representing the 4 categories and when i flip the action switch i want to see moview where `isAction = true`, and when the switch is  fliped back i want all the movies to reappear.I did solve the problem, each time the switch is flipped this function is called

```
 for(Iterator<MovieCategory> it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();){
               MovieCategory movieCategory = it.next();
               if(!MovieCategory.isAction()){
                   removed.add(new Backup(movieCategory,movieCategory.indexOf(profileCard)));
                   it.remove();
               }
           }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Whre `Backup` is

```
class Backup{
    MovieCategoty card;
    int index;

    public Backup(MovieCategoty movieCategory, int index) {
        this.movieCategory = movieCategory;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

And when the switch is flipped off again i simple call

```
 if(removed != null) {
                for (Backup b : removed) {
                    list.add(b.index, b.movieCategory);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to put everything back where it was. The issue i have with this is i have to repeat this process for every switch, which means creating 4 `ArrayList`'s and I'm worried about using too much memory because the RecyclerView can hold 10 Objects, or it can hold 50+ Objects, ie. it's not limited. So is there a better, more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: ever considered to use DiffUtil ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html